# Not able to connect to Mosquitto Server from mqtt.js

Tags: javascript, mqtt, mosquitto

I am new to wqtt server. I am trying to connect to mosquitto test server using `mqtt.js` reffering an example provided on their website.

But i am not able to connect to the server. I always get following error:

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://test.mosquitto.org/:8080/mqtt' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`.

Please help. Below is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://www.hivemq.com/demos/websocket-client/js/mqttws31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>HiveMQ MQTT Websocket Demo App</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var client = new Messaging.Client("test.mosquitto.org", 8080, "myclientid_" + parseInt(Math.random() * 100, 10));

 //Gets  called if the websocket/mqtt connection gets disconnected for any reason
 client.onConnectionLost = function (responseObject) {
     //Depending on your scenario you could implement a reconnect logic here
     alert("connection lost: " + responseObject.errorMessage);
 };

 //Gets called whenever you receive a message for your subscriptions
 client.onMessageArrived = function (message) {
     //Do something with the push message you received
     $('#messages').append('Topic: ' + message.destinationName + '  | ' + message.payloadString + '');
 };

 //Connect Options
 var options = {
     timeout: 3,
     //Gets Called if the connection has sucessfully been established
     onSuccess: function () {
         alert("Connected");
     },
     //Gets Called if the connection could not be established
     onFailure: function (message) {

        document.write("Connection failed: " + message.errorMessage);
         alert("Connection failed: " + message.errorMessage);
     }
 };

 //Creates a new Messaging.Message Object and sends it to the HiveMQ MQTT Broker
 var publish = function (payload, topic, qos) {
     //Send your message (also possible to serialize it as JSON or protobuf or just use a string, no limitations)
     var message = new Messaging.Message(payload);
     message.destinationName = topic;
     message.qos = qos;
     client.send(message);
 }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="client.connect(options);">1. Connect</button>
    <button onclick="client.subscribe('testtopic/#', {qos: 2}); alert('Subscribed');">2. Subscribe</button>
    <button onclick="publish('Hello Foo !','testtopic/bar',2);">3. Publish</button>
    <button onclick="client.disconnect();">(4. Disconnect)</button>
    <div id="messages"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: The port number is still wrong in your edit. It should be 8080 for test.mosquitto.org not 8083

Comment: I tried. But not resolving the issue

Comment: The code is STILL wrong, port 8080 NOT 1883 for websockets

Comment: I hope its OK now. :)

Comment: The code as posted now (without the single quotes round the line which sets up the client) works fine

Comment: Still getting error `Connection failed: AMQJS0007E Socket error:undefined.`

Answer (score 0):

From your error message I can see 2 issues.

1. test.mosquitto.org listens for Websocket connections on 8080 not 1883
2. There should be no http:// in the url to connect to a websocket server

Also the error message does not match the details you have included in the code sample.

Comment: I tried your *solution* but no luck. Still getting same issue.